# What is the definition of the 0th element of the spin 1/2 four vector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, feynman-diagrams, effective-field-theory

Is it:
$$
S_\mu = (I, \frac{1}{2}\vec{\sigma})\quad\text{or}\quad S_\mu = (0, \frac{1}{2}\vec{\sigma})
$$

Specifically in the "CHIRAL DYNAMICS IN NUCLEONS AND NUCLEI" Bernard,Kaiser,Meißner, commonly known as the BKM review (http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9501384v1) they state on page 142, in part A of the appendix that "$S_\mu%$ [is the] covariant spin–vector". What is the definition of the zeroth element of this vector for the spin 1/2 case?

Screenshots of the relevant part of the paper I linked are provided below since it is currently down:
[image]

And here is an example of it being used in a Feynman rule:

[image]

Comment: [It looks like 0?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_angular_momentum#Spin_in_special_relativity) (In the rest frame.)

Comment: Re "it's currently down": for files submitted to arXiv as TeX/LaTeX sources (which was *everything* before 2005 or so, and is still pretty common), the arXiv server expires the PDF after a while. A decision made back when data storage was more expensive than processor time. If you are the first person to visit an old paper after some long interval, you may have to wait for the PDF to be rebuilt on the server. The timescale for this process is 1–5 minutes; the PDF of your linked paper is available again.

Comment: Your latter vector is in the rest frame. Boost it to get the former with components modified by *suitable coefficients* !

Comment: @march Thank you for posting your response. If you post this as an answer I will accept it in a bit as long as no one else has complaints.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Can you elaborate? Particularly about the "suitable coefficients"

Comment: But they are worked out in the WP article that apparently convinced you!!

Comment: @CosmasZachos apologies, I understand what you meant in your first comment now.